# React Native Element Tooltip auto Close after certain time

Tags: reactjs, react-native, popup

I want to auto close tooltip after certain time after it opens,
could've use onOpen but I don't how

https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/tooltip/#toggleaction

any Idea ? here is the code

```
function BranchToolTip(month){
switch(month){
  case 'YG':
    return 'Yogyakarta'
    break;
  case 'BL':
    return 'Bali'
    break;
  case 'PB':
    return 'Pekanbaru'
    break;
  case 'SL':
}}

<View>
<Tooltip ref={tooltipRef} delayShow={1000} toggleOnPress={true} 
   popover={<Text>{BranchToolTip(props.tableRow2.Branch)}</Text>}>
</View>
```

Where the tooltip pressed the pop up will show the return value of BranchToolTip function
and , the idea was auto close the pop up after 3 seconds or less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a combination of onOpen and ref. The below should close the tooltip after 3 seconds.

```
const tooltipRef = useRef(null);

const onOpenToolTip = () => {
     setTimeout(function(){tooltipRef.current.toggleTooltip();},3000);
   }

<Tooltip ref={tooltipRef} delayShow={1000} toggleOnPress={true} onOpen={onOpenToolTip}
   popover={<Text>{BranchToolTip(props.tableRow2.Branch)}</Text>}>
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks man this is the solution, it works
I was also tried to use const tooltipRef = useRef(null);
I didnt know the value is Null instead of True False

Comment: great! If you don't mind marking it as the answer, that would be awesome. :)